# Razorpay Order Id and Order Id not showing in razorpay dashboard(Authorized status)

Tags: javascript, php, razorpay

In test mode of Razorpay, payment details are coming except order id,using javascript, tell me how come?

```
<button type="butoon" id="paymentclick">pay amount</button>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#paymentclick').on('click', function() {
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_xxxx",
    "amount": 100, 
    "name": "MERCHANT name",
    "description": "description",
    "image": "img/logo.png",
    "handler": function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "ABC", 
        "email": 'A@A.COM',
        "contact": '+919123456780'
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "address" //customer address 
    }
}
console.log(options);
var propay = new Razorpay(options);
propay.open();
});
```

Comment: Did you solve this? 
I am facing the same problem

Comment: add order_id in var options like "order_id": order_id